# One-To-Many, Self-referencing relationship Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, uml, relational-database, aggregation

I'm trying to implement a self referencing relation in symfony but i don't know how to do this.
this photo explain the relation between the collaborator class and the Supervisor attribute which is a Collaborator type.

[image: here is the Two classes]

Comment: Do you expect us to write your code? Can you please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Check [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In yml config this should be enough:

```
Product:  
  type: entity  
  manyToOne:
    product:
      targetEntity: Product
      joinColumn:
        name: product_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

**Note:** this is a one way binding if you want a bidirectional relationship you will have to create a `oneToMany` and a `manyToOne` relation on the same entity